# Print remote servers FILENAME, MTIME in the screen using Net::SFTP::Foreign Perl Module

Tags: perl, sftp, filemtime, data-dumper

I am writing a code which need to get the file from remote server using `Net::SFTP::Foreign` Perl module.

Here is the script.

```
my $sftp = Net::SFTP::Foreign->new(
                host=>$host, 
                user=>$user, 
                password=>$pass
            );
$sftp->die_on_error("Unable to establish SFTP connection");

$sftp->setcwd($path) or die "unable to change cwd: " . $sftp->error;

my @files = $sftp->ls($path);
print Dumper(\@files);
```

Remote server connection works fine. When I print `$sftp->status` gives `0` as value which means its success.

Even in the Dumper I could see the files from the remote server in below format.

```
$VAR1 = [
          {
            'filename' => 'script.py',
            'a' => bless( {
                            'perm' => 33204,
                            'size' => 25,
                            'gid' => 1001,
                            'flags' => 15,
                            'mtime' => 1571147796,
                            'uid' => 1001,
                            'atime' => 1571655805
                          }, 'Net::SFTP::Foreign::Attributes' ),
            'longname' => '-rw-rw-r--    1 test_vk  test_vk        25 Oct 15 13:56 script.py'
          },
          {
            'a' => bless( {
                            'flags' => 15,
                            'mtime' => 1571417934,
                            'atime' => 1571655769,
                            'uid' => 1001,
                            'gid' => 1001,
                            'size' => 369,
                            'perm' => 33204
                          }, 'Net::SFTP::Foreign::Attributes' ),
            'longname' => '-rw-rw-r--    1 test_vk  test_vk       369 Oct 18 16:58 script.pl',
            'filename' => 'script.pl'
          },
          {
            'longname' => '-rw-r--r--    1 root     root            0 Oct 30 04:32 script123.pl',
            'a' => bless( {
                            'gid' => 0,
                            'size' => 0,
                            'perm' => 33188,
                            'flags' => 15,
                            'mtime' => 1572409960,
                            'uid' => 0,
                            'atime' => 1572409960
                          }, 'Net::SFTP::Foreign::Attributes' ),
            'filename' => 'script123.pl'
          },
          {
        ];
```

What I need is take out the modification time of each of the file. 
This needs to be printed like `"filename, modification_time"`. How can I take these values from the Dumper.

Answer (score 3):

According to the documentation of [Net::SFTP::Foreign](https://metacpan.org/pod/Net::SFTP::Foreign#$sftp-%3Estat($path_or_fh)), there is a `stat` method you can call to get a [Net::SFTP::Foreign::Attributes](https://metacpan.org/pod/Net::SFTP::Foreign::Attributes) instance:

```
my $attrs = $sftp->stat($path_or_fh)
```

And then ask for the `mtime`, or the one you need.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion @Miguel. I have modified the script by adding these lines. ```my $a1 = Net::SFTP::Foreign::Attributes->new();

foreach my $file( @files ){   
 my $a2 = $a1->stat($file)
  or die "remote stat command failed: ".$sftp->status;
  
 my $size  = $a2->size;
 my $mtime = $a2->mtime;

 print "file:$file, size:$size, mtime:$mtime\n";
}```. But this throws me the error ```Can't locate object method "stat" via package "Net::SFTP::Foreign::Attributes" at sftp_test.pl line 31.```. Any idea?

Comment: Don't call `stat` that way. You don't have to create a `Net::SFTP::Foreign::Attributes` instance. Get it from `$sftp->stat($path_or_fh)` call, like I wrote.